# How to highlight text with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a beginner website using HTML, CSS and JS. However, how do you highlight text using CSS tags and stuff? (is it called CSS tags??)

I'm stuck and nothing seems to work on the internet, whatever I find.

I did this:

```html
Trying out <mark>highlighted text<mark> now!
```

Doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There Are 3 Ways TO Do It:
Way 1: Inline CSS:
`<h2 style="background-color:red;">Hi Its Highlited</h2>`
Way 2: CSS in head Section:
Your File Will Look Like This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        h2{
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hi Its Highlited</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Way 3: External CSS:
Your HTML Will Look Like This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS_DIRECTORY_HERE">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hi Its Highlited</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Replace CSS_DIRECTORY_HERE With Your CSS File Directory.
Your CSS File Will Look Like This:

```
h2{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Note: If You Are using Another Tag Like  or Any Else,
make sure Its A Text Tag.
And Replace h2 With That tag.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML/CSS you can highlight text using tag named as a mark but please keep in mind that we need to close html tags.

```
Trying out <mark>highlight my text</mark> right now!
```

You can check good details here [Mark Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_mark.asp)

Comment: It Will Also Work, But My answer is using css,
You Can Also CSS This TAG